# Trying to remove categories only if the categories dont have subcategories

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have categories and subcategories and Im trying to do a system like if I want to remove a category I only can do that if I remove my subcategories first.

My subcategories have the id_father of the categories.

**Like this:**

(Warnings and Technology are the Categories)

[image]

**My Problem:**

When I remove a category with subcategories not appear my error message that I have in code below (*This category has subcategories*) and the category  is in fact removed from my database.

I have reviewed the code many times but I can not understand where the error is.

Can you please give me a little help?

**My php code:**

```
if(!empty($_GET['deleteCategory']))
    {   
     $idDel = $_GET['deleteCategory'];
     $readDeleteCategory = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories where id_father = ?");  
     $readDeleteCategory->bindValue(1, $idDel);
     $num_rows_ReadDeleteCategory = $readDeleteCategory->rowCount();
     //if dont return results we have the delete and show the message
    if(! $num_rows_ReadDeleteCategory >=1)
        {
        $deleteCategory = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM categories WHERE id =?");
        $deleteCategory->bindValue(1,$idDel);
        $deleteCategory->execute();
        echo 'category removed with sucess.';   
            }
    else
        {
        echo 'This category has subcategories. Remove subcategories first.';
        }
     }


if(!empty($_GET['deleteSubcategory']))
    {
    $idDel = $_GET['deleteSubcategory'];
    $deleteCategory = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM categories WHERE id =?");
    $deleteCategory->bindValue(1,$idDel);
    $deleteCategory->execute();
    echo 'Category removed with sucess.';
    }
```

Comment: Use foreign key with your table.

Comment: Not going to look thru all that but maybe a simple `DELETE FROM categories WHERE id=? AND id_father=NULL`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but didnt work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just missing a simple line.

```
 $readDeleteCategory->bindValue(1, $idDel);
 $readDeleteCategory->execute();
 $num_rows_ReadDeleteCategory = $readDeleteCategory->rowCount();
```

Comment: grr..Idont know how I forgot it, I was hours here looking for the error and nothing! Thank you really :)